# Como puedo agregar una nueva colección de elementos a un Objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular7

Tengo un Objeto JSON que viene desde mi base de datos MongoDB. Este objeto lo estoy utilizando para mostrarlo en un elemento Select de HTML (Solo muestro el campo "graDes").

Quiero agregar un nuevo elemento para poder tener como primer Item una opcion que diga "Seleccione Grado".

Para esto vi la alternativa de agregar un nuevo elemento al JSON mediante Typescript.

Eh intentado muchas formas pero no logre resultado :(
Agradeceria me dieran alguna recomendacion, gracias.

```
[
    {
        "estCod": {
            "_id": "5d82a03b2cfab80f3cb9cd7a",
            "estCod": "001",
            "estNom": "Activo",
            "estDes": "...",
            "timestamp": "2019-09-18T21:23:07.222Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "_id": "5da9584878ec3e12004f670b",
        "graNum": "5",
        "graDes": "5to Grado",
        "colCod": {
            "estCod": "5d82a03b2cfab80f3cb9cd7a",
            "_id": "5d8d1b245393e91480b3447b",
            "colNom": "Siervos de Jesus",
            "colRuc": "12345678962",
            "timestamp": "2019-09-26T20:10:12.012Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "timestamp": "2019-10-18T06:14:32.175Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "estCod": {
            "_id": "5d82a03b2cfab80f3cb9cd7a",
            "estCod": "001",
            "estNom": "Activo",
            "estDes": "...",
            "timestamp": "2019-09-18T21:23:07.222Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "_id": "5da95e3978ec3e12004f6713",
        "graNum": "2",
        "graDes": "2do Grado",
        "colCod": {
            "estCod": "5d82a03b2cfab80f3cb9cd7a",
            "_id": "5d8d1b245393e91480b3447b",
            "colNom": "Siervos de Jesus",
            "colRuc": "12345678962",
            "timestamp": "2019-09-26T20:10:12.012Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "timestamp": "2019-10-18T06:39:53.702Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si los valores del json ya estan parseados y se encuentran en un array, puedes ingresar un valor al inicio de este con unshift()

```
var items = JSON.parse(); //Aqui parseas el json
items.unshift({
    "_id": "nuevo id",
    "graDes": "Valor de graDes"
});
```

Esto agregará un objeto personalizado al array

Comment: Gracias amigo!! Eres un genio!!!